# Boost Shared Pointer Constructors/Destructors

Tags: c++, boost, constructor, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I'm trying to implement smart pointers in my code. I've created a class to convert a Point to a shared_ptr and I've added a print function for the shared_ptr. In my main, I create an array of shared_ptr of type Shape. When I assign Points to the array, I only see raw constructors/destructors, rather than the shared constructor/destructors. Is this code correct?

Thanks.

```
#include "Point_H.hpp"
#include "Shape_H.hpp"
#include "Array_H.hpp"
#include "boost/shared_ptr.hpp"

using namespace CLARK::Containers;
using namespace CLARK::CAD;

class P1
{
private:
    boost::shared_ptr<Point> pp;

public:
    P1(boost::shared_ptr<Point> value) : pp(value) { cout << "P1 constructor call (default)" << endl; }
    virtual ~P1() { cout << "P1 destructor call" << endl; }
    void print() const { cout << "Point: " << *pp << endl; }
};

void Print()
{       
        boost::shared_ptr<Point> myPoint (new Point);
        {
            P1 point1(myPoint);
            point1.print();
        }           
}    

int main()
{   

    // Typedef for a shared pointer to shape
    // a typedef for an array with shapes stored as shared pointers.
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Shape> ShapePtr;
    typedef Array<ShapePtr> ShapeArray;

    ShapeArray my_ShapeArray(3);

    ShapePtr my_Point (new Point(3.1459, 3.1459));

    my_ShapeArray[0] = my_Point;

    my_ShapeArray[0]->Print();

    return 0;    
}
```

The output looks like the below (the constructor/destructor statements are from the Point/Shape/Array classes themselves, rather than from the code in this source file.

> > Array constructor call
> >
> > Shape constructor call (default)
> >
> > Point constructor call (3.1459,3.1459) ID:41
> >
> > Point destructor call
> >
> > Shape destructor call
> >
> > Array destructor call

I was expecting to see shared_ptr constructor/destructor statements. Is my problem in the P1 code or in my implementation in the main or elsewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: `shared_ptr` is not a one-size-fits-all solution.  In fact, it's almost always the wrong solution.  If the array owns the objects, and other functions only use objects while they are also contained in the array, use a collection of `unique_ptr` and then pass raw pointers (or references) to the other functions.

Comment: You actually may want one of ptr_vector and friends from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling

```
my_ShapeArray[0]->Print();
```

which must be a member function of Shape.

You are not calling the

```
Print();
```

function which you define in the code given and which is the one using the P1 class.

Comment: Wow, you're absolutely right. I can't believe I missed that. I guess that's the danger in calling everything "Print". However, now it's printing a default point (0,0), instead of the point I'm trying to print from the array (3.1459, 3.1549). So then, my Print statement in this code needs to be adjusted, but how?

Thanks!

Comment: @Clark: It looks like you are trying to override a base class `Print` function, with a capital `P`.  But your derived function is `print`, with a lowercase `p`, so it's a new function and not an override.

Comment: Your Print function in this code does not accept an argument, it creates a new Point.  Try passing in the Point from the array and using that instead of myPoint.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling any single bit from your code in the `main` function... You never instantiate `P1`, you never call the standalone function `Print`, so how could any of your logging statement ever get called?